# Changing the center of a quad for rotation purposes in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, rotation, opengl-es-2.0, translation

All

Using the code below my quad moves position.  However, I don't want this to happen, all I'm after is for the center of rotation to move.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Note, If I place a translate function before the rotate it has no effect whatsoever.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

```
Matrix.setIdentityM(mRotationMatrix, 0);

Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, 45, 0, 0, 0.1f);

Matrix.translateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, quadCenterX, quadCenterY, 0f);

// Combine the rotation matrix with the projection and camera view
Matrix.multiplyMM(mvpMatrix2, 0, mvpMatrix, 0,  mRotationMatrix, 0);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To rotate around a different center of rotation:

```
Matrix.setIdentityM(mRotationMatrix, 0);

Matrix.translateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, quadCenterX, quadCenterY, 0f);
Matrix.rotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, 45, 0, 0, 0.1f);
Matrix.translateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, -quadCenterX, -quadCenterY, 0f);
```

Note that you have to use `rotateM` instead of `setRotateM`, as setRotateM overwrites the previous Matrix.

Comment: Thank you so much @i47 - I've been going over and over this for so long, and it was simply because I was using setRotateM rather than rotateM - you're the first one to notice that!  And it works :-) so once again, thanks!!